# Can CAST and CONVERT be used in a table creation

Tags: sql

I have never tried this sort of SQL query before, so excuse me for asking this question.  Is it possible to use CAST and CONVERT in a table creation?

```
   create table Owner
(
    Id      int identity(0,1) 
,   Name        nvarchar(200)
,   CountryId   int
,   PolicyNumber    AS (CONVERT(CountryId AS char(3)) + CONVERT(Id AS char(10)) varchar(40)
)
go
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called [computed columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) but you use it wrong:

```
create table Owner(
    Id          int identity(0,1) 
   ,Name        nvarchar(200)
   ,CountryId   int
   ,PolicyNumber AS (CAST(CountryId AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10)))
)
go
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/427054)**</kbd>

1. No need for final datatype so remove `varchar(40)`
2. [`CAST(col AS datatype)` or `CONVERT(datatype, col, style)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Don't mix them.
3. If you use SQL `Server 2012+` use simple `CONCAT`:

   ```
   create table Owner(
       Id      int identity(0,1) 
      ,Name        nvarchar(200)
      ,CountryId   int
      ,PolicyNumber AS (CONCAT(CountryId, Id)));
   go
   ```

You should also:

- add `NOT NULL` and `PRIMARY KEY` to `Id`
- add `REFERENCES` to `CountryId` and make it `NOT NULL` also
- add separator to computed column like `-` between both number(see demo)